# Problem with reading multiple texture units from a Shader in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to read two different textures in my shader, one for regular texturing, and one bumpmap. However both Sampler2D's are reading from the same texture unit. I am setting the uniforms to 0 and 1 however, and I have bound the textures to their respective units as follows:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texMgr->GetTexture("stone")->texture);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texMgr->GetTexture("bump")->texture);
```

In my render loop I set the uniforms as follows:

```
shaderMgr->activeProgram()->setUniform1f("tex", 0);
shaderMgr->activeProgram()->setUniform1f("norm", 1);
```

And finally my shader code:

```
varying vec4 colorVarying;
varying vec4 normalVarying;
varying vec3 lightDirVarying;
varying vec2 textureCoordinateVarying;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D norm;

void main() {    
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(tex, textureCoordinateVarying);
    vec4 normColor = texture2D(norm, textureCoordinateVarying);
    vec3 newNormal = vec3(2.0 * normColor.x - 1.0, 2.0 * normColor.y - 1.0, 2.0 * normColor.z - 1.0);
    vec3 normal = normalize(normalVarying.xyz + newNormal);
    float diff = max(0.0, dot(normal, normalize(lightDirVarying)));

    gl_FragColor = texColor * (diff + 0.3);
}
```

I only call glActiveTexture in my renderloop every time I draw an Object, and I only call glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1) once (in my initialization).

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, object->tex->texture);
```

Everything is working fine for the first texture, but the second texture (Bump) isn't showing up. I've tried:

- Adding ARB to everything, I'm not sure if this matters. (I'm on OSX 10.6 if that is of any use)
- Adding glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) every time I switch texture units.
- Not switching between programs, and just run with one shaders, and set the uniforms in my initialization
- Resetting the texture params every time I switch texture units.
- Not switching between TextureUnits, and only initialize them at the start
- Started a new project, only copied the relevant code and ran it, kept it as small as possible

All these things didn't help, the norm sampler is solely reading the GL_TEXTURE0 unit.

I have been searching for hours now, and I still haven't found the answer. I have no idea what I am doing wrong and why my norm sampler isn't reading from the proper GL_TEXTURE1 unit.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, which is already answered anyway, but those glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) calls have no effect on the programmable pipeline. Check out http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_:_common_mistakes

Comment: Yeah I fixed that already :) Thanks though, many things on that page I didn't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
shaderMgr->activeProgram()->setUniform1f("tex", 0);
```

If this is calling glUniform1f, that's wrong, you must use glUniform1i to set texture samplers.